# Windows 7 ROP Functions mapped to 0x00########

Tags: windows, exploit

I am currently working on learning Windows Exploitation and am working in a Windows 7 VM. I was going through some tutorials and while they worked fine on Vista and below, they won't on Windows 7 due to a new restriction.

The restriction is that addresses that I could use for ROP are now mapped to 0x00 and which contains a NULL byte. This is also the same with potential gadgets like "call esp, jmp esp, etc"

```
!mona rop

# rop chain generated with mona.py - www.corelan.be
 rop_gadgets = [
   0x0045021d,  # POP EAX # RETN [Eureka Email.exe]
   0x004570a8,  # ptr to &VirtualAlloc() [IAT Eureka Email.exe]
   0x004124d4,  # MOV EAX,DWORD PTR DS:[EAX] # RETN [Eureka Email.exe]
   0x004412d7,  # PUSH EAX # PUSHAD # XOR EAX,EAX # POP ESI # RETN [Eureka Email.exe]
   0x00446d9f,  # POP EBP # RETN [Eureka Email.exe]
   0x00415e82,  # & push esp # ret  [Eureka Email.exe]
```

How do I bypass this new restriction in Windows 7? In Linux I know this is "ASCII Guard" but I am not familiar with it in Windows nor did I know it was a thing.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you just can't ROP if your vulnerable function breaks on null terminated strings.

However, you still have some other options:

- Try to find a memory leak condition. You get at least one return address before the last null byte breaks your payload, and build a 2nd stage exploit
- You could write a ROP chain including ASLR and re-based modules (if using mona, tell it to include modules regardless of their security: `!mona -cm aslr=true,rebase=true` and no nulls `!mona -cp nonull`) and shift relative base address offsets on the gadgets on the fly in some brute-force tries. You might get lucky and land just fine as 32 bits address space entropy is very reduced.